# Connect to MySQL Database Remotely

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a MySQL database hosted on one site, and I want to connect to it from another site, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @rar your server ? shared hosting ?

Comment: Also look at this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/

Comment: You must to ask host provider !
to see if they use localhost for her Databases or other server like server.somesite.com but the most host providers use localhost

Comment: Mysql server can be easily accessed ... are you sure there is nothing more to the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You would have to configure MySQL to allow access from the remote server, and ensure that any intervening firewalls allow the MySQL port to go through.

For more info see

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html